# PHP logout fails to log user out

Tags: php, session, logout

my name is Sven and im experiencing a problem with loggin out of my site.
My login code is the following:

```
$_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
header("location:success.php");
```

I've tried several logout codes like `session_destroy();` and `session_unset();`
but non of them seems to log the user probertly out.
Please help

Comment: post your code...you're showing login code, but not logout code....who knows you may just have a simple syntax error......but without the LOGOUT code, we can't help

Comment: What indication do you have that the user is not logged out?

Comment: Is `session_start();` also present at the **top** (*first line*) of your code?

Comment: `$_SESSION['userName'] = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your actual logout code....Im just gonna go ahead and take a wild guess here....

My guess is you just didn't include `session_start();`  at the top of your logout script....

95% of the time, that is the reason for logouts failing.  Is that people just call `session_destroy()`  but they forget that they still have to start the session on that page, so that the destroy() function knows there is a session to destroy...

Let me know if that was your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I have this code:

```
session_name('frontpage');
session_start('frontpage');
session_unset('frontpage');
session_destroy();
header("Location:index.php");
```

I hope may help you

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be on top

Comment: Theoretically, your answer will hit a brick wall and **fail** .

Comment: Btw, are you the original OP by any chance (user2372837)? * *head scratch* *